# Is there method level permission in OSGi?

Tags: java, permissions, osgi

Is there method level permission in OSGi?

I am using Conditional Permission Admin service to control access to my code. The only available permissions I saw in OSGi are:

> Package Permission, Service Permission and Admin Permission.

But I also want to have control over only a single Method. 
Is there may be another option combined with the Java security that will allow me to have an entry in CPA policy file to control method permission?

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to write your own permission that you will check upon entry to your method.

Comment: Thank you for your response Hrgrave, but I have not got a means to extend OSGi permission.

Comment: You do not need to extend OSGi permissions. Write your own. The OSGi security model supports user supplied permissions.

Comment: Yes, OSGi Permissions are used plain old Java Permissions. Any of the existing Java permissions as well as any user defined permissions works fine with OSGi.